# Convert float value from a db2 database to a date format?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a database from a custom application.
The values in the database for a date is `44416.254005`, and the application that uses this database resolves that number to the following date `8/8/2021 6:05:46 AM`.
Another example is `44416.268113` to `8/8/2021 6:26:05 AM`.
ex. 44328.93713 = 5/12/2021 10:29:28 PM

I have an old backup of this database and need to figure out how the conversions are made?

Comment: A bit different sample timestamps would make it easier for all of us.

Comment: 8/8/2021, is that August 8th, or 8th of August? Standard SQL wants the ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: 44328.93713 = 5/12/2021 10:29:28 PM

Comment: The integer parts means days since 1899-12-30.

Comment: And the decimal part means how much of a day. E.g. `.750000` means `6:00:00 PM`.

Comment: Is this a standard method used by the original developer? Is there any online calculator i can use to do the conversions?

Comment: I have never seen it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the an Excel format for a date.  If so, you can convert to seconds and add to `1899-12-31`:

```
select timestamp '1899-12-31 00:00:00' + (44416.268113 * 60 * 60 * 24) second
```

Comment: I need a formula for only the decimal part to convert it to regular time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

def xldate_to_datetime(xldate):
    start = datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=xldate)
    return start + delta
```